# How DNS name will be resolved in this case?

Tags: web-applications, dns

Say i have below  entry under host file . Also i have windows Domain name server which maps test.com to some other IP. My question is will test.com be resolved
against host file entry or DNS server ?

```
 192.11.123.13  test.com
```

Comment: I think first it will go to the host file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For windows clients, this is the [Host Name Resolution Order](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/172218)

1. The client checks to see if the name queried is its own
2. The client then searches a local Hosts file
3. Domain Name System (DNS) servers are queried
4. If the name is still not resolved, NetBIOS name resolution sequence is used